# How long does it take to fill a $100\ \mathrm{m^2}$ room with new air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, air, gas

How long does it take to fill a $100\ \mathrm{m^2}$ room with new air.

For example. If the room is $100\ \mathrm{m^2}$ room. The window is $1\ \mathrm{m^2}$ and is left open. How long would it take for the older air to be replaced with new air outside. Lets imagine all other variables are average

Comment: Cannot help until rate of filling air is given. How can room be $m^2$? 2D room?

Comment: For standard room and windows a rate of 7 volumes an hour can be assumed. Somehow an  engineering parameter that I remember from old class on safety.  Standard room means everything reasonably designed to serve the purpose and having enough light from not airtight windows.